# Does Moq support 'in' parameters?

Tags: c#, moq

I am trying to create a mock for an interface which has an 'in' parameter.  It's not working as I hoped.  Here's a simplified example:

```
namespace MoqExample.Test
{
    public interface IPublisher
    {
        void Publish(in int i);
    }

    public class Tests
    {
        private Mock<IPublisher> publisher;

        [SetUp]
        public void BeforeEachTest()
        {
            publisher = new Mock<IPublisher>(MockBehavior.Strict);
            publisher.Setup(publisher => publisher.Publish(It.IsAny<int>()));
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestPublishInt()
        {
            publisher.Object.Publish(1);
        }
    }
}
```

This example gives this error:

```
  Message: 
    Moq.MockException : IPublisher.Publish(1) invocation failed with mock behavior Strict.
    All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.
  Stack Trace: 
    FailForStrictMock.Handle(Invocation invocation, Mock mock)
    IInterceptor.Intercept(Invocation invocation)
    Interceptor.Intercept(IInvocation underlying)
    AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
    IPublisherProxy.Publish(Int32& i)
    Tests.TestPublishInt() line 26
```

If I remove 'in' from the interface the test passes.  But I don't have that choice in my use case.

Is this supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier), first sentence:

> The in keyword causes arguments to be passed by reference.

Try using:

```
publisher.Setup(publisher => publisher.Publish(It.Ref<int>.IsAny));
```